# Angular map flower (celery+django) return to list of tasks

Tags: django, angular, typescript, django-celery, flower

I want to map the return of the flower libary (/api/tasks) to a list of objects. Currently it returns multiple objects, but without the "list wrapper", so it's not possible to iterate that.
**API:** https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#get--api-tasks

Return is for example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1109
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Etag: "b2478118015c8b825f7b88ce6b660e5449746c37"
Server: TornadoServer/3.1.1

{
    "e42ceb2d-8730-47b5-8b4d-8e0d2a1ef7c9": {
        "args": "[3, 4]",
        "client": null,
        "clock": 1079,
        "eta": null,
        "exception": null,
        "exchange": null,
        "expires": null,
        "failed": null,
        "kwargs": "{}",
        "name": "tasks.add",
        "received": 1398505411.107885,
        "result": "'7'",
        "retried": null,
        "retries": 0,
        "revoked": null,
        "routing_key": null,
        "runtime": 0.01610181899741292,
        "sent": null,
        "started": 1398505411.108985,
        "state": "SUCCESS",
        "succeeded": 1398505411.124802,
        "timestamp": 1398505411.124802,
        "traceback": null,
        "uuid": "e42ceb2d-8730-47b5-8b4d-8e0d2a1ef7c9",
        "worker": "celery@worker1"
    },
    "f67ea225-ae9e-42a8-90b0-5de0b24507e0": {
        "args": "[1, 2]",
        "client": null,
        "clock": 1042,
        "eta": null,
        "exception": null,
        "exchange": null,
        "expires": null,
        "failed": null,
        "kwargs": "{}",
        "name": "tasks.add",
        "received": 1398505395.327208,
        "result": "'3'",
        "retried": null,
        "retries": 0,
        "revoked": null,
        "routing_key": null,
        "runtime": 0.012884548006695695,
        "sent": null,
        "started": 1398505395.3289,
        "state": "SUCCESS",
        "succeeded": 1398505395.341089,
        "timestamp": 1398505395.341089,
        "traceback": null,
        "uuid": "f67ea225-ae9e-42a8-90b0-5de0b24507e0",
        "worker": "celery@worker1"
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to do that?
I've tried the following thing:

```
export interface Tasks {
  tasks: TaskWrapper[]
}

export interface TaskWrapper {
  [uuid: string]: Task
}

export interface Task {
  uuid: string,
  state: string,
  received: string,
}
```

Added example of Dragan leads to the following problem:

```
loadAllTasksFromFlower(): Observable<Task[]> { 
return this.http.get<Task[]>("localhost:5566/api/tasks")
.pipe(map(response => Object.entries(response)
.map(entry => ({ uuid: entry[0], state: entry[1].state, received: entry[1].received }))
}
```

> TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ uuid: string; state: TaskState; received:
> any; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Task[]>'.   Type '{
> uuid: string; state: TaskState; received: any; }[]' is not assignable
> to type 'Task[]'.     Type '{ uuid: string; state: TaskState;
> received: any; }' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Task': type, source, invoke, callback, and 3 more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you organized the interfaces is good, you can put the items in the array in this way:

```
const tasks: Task[] = Object.entries(data).map(entry => ({
    uuid: entry[0],
    state: entry[1].state,
    received: entry[1].received
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What could be the possible return of my http request?
  loadAllTasksFromFlower(): Observable<Tasks> {
    return this.http.get<Tasks>("http://localhost:5566/api/tasks")
  }

Comment: loadAllTasksFromFlower(): Observable<Task[]> { return this.http.get<Task[]>("localhost:5566/api/tasks") .pipe(map(response => Object.entries(response).map(entry => ({
    uuid: entry[0],
    state: entry[1].state,
    received: entry[1].received
}))}

Comment: TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ uuid: string; state: any; received: any; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Task[]>'.   Type '{ uuid: string; state: any; received: any; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Task[]'.     Type '{ uuid: string; state: any; received: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Task': type, source, invoke, callback, and 3 more.

Comment: Just change the generic type of the http get method from Tasks to Task[]

Comment: Still creating some errors: TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ uuid: string; state: TaskState; received: any; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Task[]>'.   Type '{ uuid: string; state: TaskState; received: any; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Task[]'.     Type '{ uuid: string; state: TaskState; received: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Task': type, source, invoke, callback, and 3 more.
Is there a problem with typescript? Like a conflict or something

Comment: Please edt the question with the full example and I will check what is the cause of the error

Comment: There you go. I've updated the post. I think I should return a Task object, isn't it?

Comment: Try with switchMap instead of map as pipe operator. You can return Tasks or Task[]. This example is for Task[] but you can change it to return Tasks if you need

Comment: TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ uuid: string; state: TaskState; received: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Task[]>'. It still produces an error.

Comment: How you defined TaskState ? Probably you need to update the state property of the Task interface to be TaskState instead of string

Comment: Theres no TaskState defined at all. Thats so weird. The problem is, that we do not create a "Task" object. How can I do that. It's an interface

Comment: I got it.. Task was a class by Typescript which was used instead of my Task interface..weird! Thank you so much. Its working now